# What is the difference between file://<somewhere> and file:///<somewhere>?

Tags: windows, file, uri

What is the difference between `file://<somewhere>` and `file:///<somewhere>`?

Comment: the difference is the second one has one more forward slash

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file:///some/path` is equivalent to `file://localhost/some/path`, and refers to a file named `/some/path` on the local machine, whereas `file://some/path` refers to a file named `path` on a machine named `some`.

See [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), section 3.10:

> 3.10 FILES

> The file URL scheme is used to designate files accessible on a particular host computer. This scheme, unlike most other URL schemes, does not designate a resource that is universally accessible over the Internet.

> A file URL takes the form:

> ```
>   file://<host>/<path>
> ```

> where `<host>` is the fully qualified domain name of the system on
> which the `<path>` is accessible, and `<path>` is a hierarchical
> directory path of the form `<directory>/<directory>/.../<name>`.

> For example, a VMS file

> ```
>    DISK$USER:[MY.NOTES]NOTE123456.TXT
> ```

> might become

> ```
>    <URL:file://vms.host.edu/disk$user/my/notes/note12345.txt>
> ```

> As a special case, `<host>` can be the string "localhost" or the empty
> string; this is interpreted as `the machine from which the URL is
> being interpreted'.

`file://<path>` happens to work a lot of the time when you try to use it as a URL, because  the error is common enough that many programs just assume it's going to happen.  But it's ambiguous at best, and downright wrong at worst.